# Very short-term drop in stock price

Tags: stocks, price, volatility, short-term

When looking at stock price charts, you sometimes see a large drop in the price for just a short amount of time.

[image]

Is this simply an error in the presentation of the chart, or has the price *actually* dropped that much? If the latter, can someone explain how this is possible? And are there ways to benefit from such volatility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's almost certainly bad data for a stock as liquid (highly traded) as Tesla. Look at the charts from other sites and see if you see the same data - I'm betting you don't.

Comment: Good point. I don't see it on Yahoo Finance. Indeed, plotting error.

Comment: Is it possible that options were executed at that price ? Seems to be around the reasonable price for an option from a year ago or so

Comment: @xyious No, option exercise is not reflected in the market price of stocks. It's bad data.